# Datatypes to return in GeoServer WPS

Tags: geoserver, wps

Is it possible, that my created WPS (in Geoserver) returns an image or a pdf (general: returns a datatype, that isn't a supported format by Geoserver).

Is it sufficient to expand the ProcessParameterIO class?

Can anybody give me a general overview, how to do that?